# How to use "delegate" instead of "live"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've read countless articles how using the jQuery [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is much more efficient than using the "live" event.

As such, I'm having trouble converting my existing live code to using delegate:

```
$("#tabs li:eq(0)").live('click',function(){ //...code });
$('#A > div.listing, #B > div.listing, #C > div.listing').live('mouseover',function(){ // ...code });
```

When I replace the previous code with what I assume is more efficient delegate code, my page doesn't load.

```
$("#tabs li:eq(0)").delegate('click',function(){ //...code });
$('#A > div.listing, #B > div.listing, #C > div.listing').delegate('mouseover',function(){ // ...code });
```

Any idea why my delegate code doesn't work? Also, any suggestions on how to make this more efficient?

**UPDATE**:

The think part of the problem is that, both "#tabs" and "#A, #B, #C" are't present on the web page at page load. Those attributes are dynamically inserted onto the page with an AJAX call. As such, does that mean I have to use live over delegate?

Answer (score 2):

**Update for your update :)** - Yes, stick with `.live()` if this is the case, unless your DOM is *very* deep, there's an infinitesimally small difference in performance.

---

**Previous answer:**  Your delegate functions should look like this:

```
$("#tabs").delegate('li:eq(0)', 'click', function(){ //...code });
$('#A, #B, #C').delegate('> div.listing', 'mouseover', function(){ // ...code });
```

This depends on `#tabs` not being in the content that's replaced as part of any ajax call, the same for `#A`, `#B`, and `#C`.  The format for [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is this:

```
$(selectorOrNonReplacedParent).delegate(childSelector, event, function);
```

Comment: @Nick Craver, The problem is that, both *"#tabs"* and *"#A, #B, #C"* are't present on the web page at page load. Those attributes are dynamically inserted onto the page with an AJAX call. As such, when I made the change per your code - my page still doesn't load. Any ideas what's causing my problem?

Comment: @JacobD - If those aren't present, then you need to either stick with `.live()` or go to a higher ancestor that *does* exist when you're doing this binding.  `.delegate()` actually uses `.live()`, it's not a full replacement.